# Toggle between dark and light theme in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, android-10, themes

**Can we toggle between light and dark theme in Maps?**

Maps has shown a message after a new [update asking to choose between dark and light theme](https://9to5google.com/2021/03/18/google-maps-dark-theme-android/). After selection (dark, which was illegibly dark under daylight and especially sunlight, or maybe it's my presbyopia) the way to switch out of that without changing the whole system theme was to uninstall (downgrade) the app, update it and then chose the light theme when aforementioned message popped up again. My system theme is dark, and I want it that way, but I don't want dark for Maps, except maybe when it's really dark *outside*.

Maps 10.62.1
Android 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change it from settings (to access settings, tap on the icon with user initial/user profile icon, next to microphone), then theme, wherein the same dialogue pops up, that you had initially to choose a theme.

[image: image of Google Maps app UI]

[image: image of Google Maps UI to toggle between dark and light themes]

Tested on Android 10 & 11, Maps version `10.62.1`